# Get parameters of Jenkins build by job name and build id

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am using Jenkins Pipeline plugin and I need to get all parameters of particular build by its id and job name from other job. 
So, basically i need something like this.

```
def job = JobRegistry.getJobByName(jobName)
def build = job.getBuild(buildId)
Map parameters = build.getParameters()
println parameters['SOME_PARAMETER']
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured it out.
I can retrieve parameters like this

```
def parameters = Jenkins.instance.getAllItems(Job)
                        .find {job -> job.fullName == jobName }
                        .getBuildByNumber(buildId.toInteger())
                        .getAction(hudson.model.ParametersAction)

println parameters.getParameter('SOME_PARAMETER').value
```

Comment: You can skip the `find` with `Jenkins.getInstance().getItemByFullName(jobName)` ; see https://stackoverflow.com/a/43633307/398670

Comment: This `.getAction(hudson.model.ParametersAction)`  always returns `null` :(

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you to review "Pipeline Syntax" in a pipeline job, at bottom of Pipeline plugin, and you can see Global Variable Reference, like docker/pipeline/env/etc.

So what you need, JOB_NAME / BUILD_ID is given in "env" list

Comment: I do not need job name and build id of current job. I need to retrieve parameters of some another build from another job.

Comment: then what about using curl to activate another job? in this way you could bring parameters